# Can't put list of <li> elements in one column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an html-file with `<ul>` list there:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Whitesquare</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/script.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header class="row">
            <a class="span2" href="/"><img src="./logo.png" alt="Whitesquare logo"></a>
            <div class="span2 offset6" id="reminders">Напоминания</div>
            <div class="span2" id="administration">Администрация</div>
        </header>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="navbar span2">
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                    <li class="active" id="statistics">Статистика</li>
                    <li id="LPU">ЛПУ</li> 
                    <li id="content">Состав</li>
                    <li id="add">Добавить</li>
                    <li id="addParticipant">Добавить участника</li>
                    <li id="addLPU">Добавить ЛПУ</li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="mainContent" class="span10">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Two of them are invisible and I add with them with help of javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mainContent").load("statistics.html");
    $("ul.nav-stacked> li").click(function(){
        if($(this).attr("id")!="add"){
            if($(this).attr("class")!="active"){
                $("ul.nav-stacked li").removeClass("active");
                $(this).attr("class","active");
                var contentForLoad=$(this).attr("id")+".html";
                $("#mainContent").load(contentForLoad);
            }
        }
        else{
            if(($(this).attr("class")!="active")&&($("#addParticipant").attr("class")!="active")&&($("#addLPU").attr("class")!="active")){
                $("ul.nav-stacked li").removeClass("active");
                $(this).attr("class","active");
                $("#addParticipant").css("opacity","1");
                $("#addLPU").css("opacity","1");
            }
            else{
                $("ul.nav-stacked li").removeClass("active");
                $("#addParticipant").css("opacity","0");
                $("#addLPU").css("opacity","0");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

For some reason when I have

```
<li class="active" id="statistics">option1</li>
<li id="LPU">option2</li> 
<li id="add">add</li>
<li id="addParticipant">add option1</li>
<li id="addLPU">add option2</li>
```

It's ok in 1 column, but when I add option3 at top:

```
<li class="active" id="statistics">option1</li>
<li id="LPU">option2</li>
<li>option3</li> 
<li id="add">add</li>
<li id="addParticipant">add option1</li>
<li id="addLPU">add option2</li>
```

option2 and option3 are in one string.
What can be a reason?
[image]

Comment: You seem to be calling `$("#wrapper").ready(function(){` but this should be done on the document eg `$(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: thanx, but mistake is the same.

Comment: What is `wrapper`? Can't find it in your code.

Comment: can u give us a fiddle? its difficult to replicate your problem just by reading it....

Comment: Yep, changed wrapper to document

Comment: Like this in picture.

Comment: +1 can u give us a fiddle

Comment: @SergeyScopin : this is a fiddle => http://jsfiddle.net/T7ta4/ , i made up ur code here, its gud to have live demo of ur basic code....not replicate your issue here and update the fiddle :)